# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in python 3.x Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to count some instances per hour time in a large dataset. The code below seems to work fine on python 2.7 but I had to upgrade it to 3.x latest version of python with all updated packages on Anaconda. When I am trying to execute the program I am getting following `str` error

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,time
import numpy as np

fn = r'00_input.csv'
cols = ['UserId', 'UserMAC', 'HotspotID', 'StartTime', 'StopTime']
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime

# 'start' and 'end' for the reporting DF: `r`
# which will contain equal intervals (1 hour in this case)
start = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime.min(), unit='s').date()
end = pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime.max(), unit='s').date() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# building reporting DF: `r`
freq = '1H'  # 1 Hour frequency
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
r['start'] = (r.index - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds().astype(np.int64)

# 1 hour in seconds, minus one second (so that we will not count it twice)
interval = 60*60 - 1

r['LogCount'] = 0
r['UniqueIDCount'] = 0

for i, row in r.iterrows():
        # intervals overlap test
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test
        # i've slightly simplified the calculations of m and d
        # by getting rid of division by 2,
        # because it can be done eliminating common terms
    u = df[np.abs(df.m - 2*row.start - interval) < df.d + interval].UserID
    r.ix[i, ['LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount']] = [len(u), u.nunique()]

r['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.date
r['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.weekday_name.str[:3]
r['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.time
r['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start + interval + 1, unit='s').dt.time

#r.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
#print(r[r.LogCount > 0])
#print (r['StartTime'], r['EndTime'], r['Day'], r['LogCount'], r['UniqueIDCount'])

rout =  r[['Date', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Day', 'LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount'] ]
#print rout
rout.to_csv('o_1_hour.csv', index=False, header=False
```

)

Where do I make changes to get a error free execution

Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 686, in <lambda>
    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Appreciate the Help, Thanks in advance

Comment: What return `print (df['StartTime'].dtypes)` and `print (df['StopTime'].dtypes)` after `df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols, parse_dates=[3,4])` ?

Comment: @jezrael It isn't even considering the print statements, After changes mentioned the Answer below and including the print statements i am getting this error `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Ok, but I cannot find error without it - so is impossible get this `dtypes` for some reason? Because if it is object, is necessary `to_datetime(df['StartTime'], errros='coerce')` and if it is `datetime64` then problem is different. Also first row of error is necessary too, becasue obviously show error code row.

Comment: But if data are not confidental, you can share it by dropbox, gdocs or send me it to my email in my profile. Because without data it is really difficult find problem :(

Comment: The data is not confidential but it is too large in size (GBs) I have uploaded a mini version of the data in dropbox here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2lzimxks26a3bw/canada_mini_unixtime.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need change `header=0` for select first row to header - then column names are replace by list `cols`.

If still problem, need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), because some values in `StartTime` and `StopTime` are strings, which are parsed to `NaN`, replace by `0` an last convert column to `int`:

```
cols = ['UserId', 'UserMAC', 'HotspotID', 'StartTime', 'StopTime']
df = pd.read_csv('canada_mini_unixtime.csv', header=0, names=cols)
#print (df)

df['StartTime'] = pd.to_numeric(df['StartTime'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
df['StopTime'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['StopTime'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

No change:

```
df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime
start = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime.min(), unit='s').date()
end = pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime.max(), unit='s').date() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

freq = '1H'  # 1 Hour frequency
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
r['start'] = (r.index - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds().astype(np.int64)

# 1 hour in seconds, minus one second (so that we will not count it twice)
interval = 60*60 - 1

r['LogCount'] = 0
r['UniqueIDCount'] = 0
```

`ix` is deprecated in last version of pandas, so use `loc` and column name is in `[]`:

```
for i, row in r.iterrows():
        # intervals overlap test
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test
        # i've slightly simplified the calculations of m and d
        # by getting rid of division by 2,
        # because it can be done eliminating common terms
    u = df.loc[np.abs(df.m - 2*row.start - interval) < df.d + interval, 'UserId']
    r.loc[i, ['LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount']] = [len(u), u.nunique()]

r['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.date
r['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.weekday_name.str[:3]
r['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.time
r['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start + interval + 1, unit='s').dt.time

print (r)
```

Comment: Sure ..Thank you .. I'll make the changes and try to execute the program and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: I have a bunch of code to migrate from 2.7 to 3.x .. I hope this works for me .. One down from count of pending heap also counts.. Thanks a bunch ..

Comment: Yes, I starts with python 2 also, I know what is it. Good luck!

Comment: Gives me error in another place ` in <module>
    u = df[np.abs(df.StartTime - 2*row.start - interval) < df.StopTime + interval].UserID`   `TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [__sub__]`

Comment: Hmmm, I was wrong. Ther is another problem. I edit answer.

Comment: I made all the changed you mention in the answer .. But unformtunately the outputs are `0` This is a program to find log of connections every hour and unique connections in one hour.

Comment: Are you sure data are OK? Is possible test it in python 2 if same output?

Comment: Yes i am sure the Python 2 version works as I have generated outputs for datasets. I will work on python 2 code for the same dataset and let you know.

Comment: The python 2.7 execution output in the dropbox, But rolling back and working with this dataset and the same programming isnt working .. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcx683fgqctsqte/o_1_hour.csv?dl=0

Comment: Thank you, but now I am offline only on phone. Is possible send me your python 2 code with some sample data on my email? Because still dont understand difference, code should work same way in python 2 and python 3. If data confidental, is possinle anonymize it?

Comment: Sure I can share the code and input samples from a folder on dropbox, this data is already anonymous. Please can you share your email id ..

Comment: Shared the dropbox repository

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I think you can see new file `0_time_split_jez.py`. But I am a bit confused - How is possible compare outputs if not same inputs? Also I think there is problem in something else, because no `python 2` to `python 3` conversion like `map`, `print` ... What do you think?

Comment: The 'dart' input n output both are given,  input dart is mini version and the Canada mini input is wat I want to work on now.. It might not be only python 2 or 3 but also the supporting packages like pandas,  numpy and others,  I did try to downgrade them aswell and check.  But looks like getting the combination of same working versions a bit time taking process..  Hence i wanted to upgrade the code

Comment: Ok, I try Canada mini input, but how I can check if output is correct if impossible compare with `o_1_hour.csv` ? Minimal there is difference in length and in dates (`2010` vs `2004` years)

Comment: Can I add u on Google hangout chat? Please

Comment: invitation sent

Comment: I did from my Gmail u have to accept it "phani.lav()gmail()com"

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

`df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime` is attempting to subtract a string from another string. I don't know what your data looks like, but chances are that you want to parse `StopTime` and `StartTime` as dates. Try

```
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols, parse_dates=[3,4])
```

instead of `df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: When I changed the statement I am getting this error `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`