# int - String Type error while converting datetime to Unix Time epoch

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert Datetime to Unix time epoch but I am getting following error.

Input:

```
userid,datetime,latitude,longitude
156,2014-02-01 00:00:00.739166+01,41.8836718276551,12.4877775603346
187,2014-02-01 00:00:01.148457+01,41.9285433333333,12.4690366666667
297,2014-02-01 00:00:01.220066+01,41.8910686119733,12.4927045625339
89,2014-02-01 00:00:01.470854+01,41.7931766914244,12.4321219603157
79,2014-02-01 00:00:01.631136+01,41.90027472,12.46274618
191,2014-02-01 00:00:02.048546+01,41.8523047579646,12.5774065771898
343,2014-02-01 00:00:02.647839+01,41.8921718255185,12.4696996165151
341,2014-02-01 00:00:02.709888+01,41.9102125627332,12.4770004336041
260,2014-02-01 00:00:03.458195+01,41.8658208551143,12.4655221109313
```

Program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', 
                 #header=None, #no header in csv
                 header=['userid','datetime','latitude','longitude'], #set custom column names
                 parse_dates=['datetime']) #parse columns d, e to datetime

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
#df['e'] = df['e'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

df.to_csv('output.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

The above program worked fine when in python 2.7 but not that I have upgraded to python 3.x Anaconda I am not able to get results

Error:

```
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 519, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:5907)

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

**Edit:** input file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sepflvjvpkliewq/input_header.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` argument in [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) expects an int or list of ints not a list of strings.

```
from io import StringIO
file="""
userid,datetime,latitude,longitude
156,2014-02-01 00:00:00.739166+01,41.8836718276551,12.4877775603346
187,2014-02-01 00:00:01.148457+01,41.9285433333333,12.4690366666667
297,2014-02-01 00:00:01.220066+01,41.8910686119733,12.4927045625339
89,2014-02-01 00:00:01.470854+01,41.7931766914244,12.4321219603157
79,2014-02-01 00:00:01.631136+01,41.90027472,12.46274618
191,2014-02-01 00:00:02.048546+01,41.8523047579646,12.5774065771898
343,2014-02-01 00:00:02.647839+01,41.8921718255185,12.4696996165151
341,2014-02-01 00:00:02.709888+01,41.9102125627332,12.4770004336041
260,2014-02-01 00:00:03.458195+01,41.8658208551143,12.4655221109313"""
```

Let's try this read_csv statement:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file),parse_dates=['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

print(df.head())
```

output:

```
   userid    datetime   latitude  longitude
0     156  1391209200  41.883672  12.487778
1     187  1391209201  41.928543  12.469037
2     297  1391209201  41.891069  12.492705
3      89  1391209201  41.793177  12.432122
4      79  1391209201  41.900275  12.462746
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer But I am getting following error : `ValueError: 'datetime' is not in list` same input from csv file no changes at all

Comment: Can you paste the first three lines of your CSV file here?

Comment: I have given the input file as as link you can download from there

Comment: That should work.  And you are executing the same pd.read_cvs I have here just changed the StringIO(file) to your correct path to expected csv file?  Make sure parse_dates=['datetime'] with brackets to indicate list.

Comment: I did use the same code you have written and yes the paths are in same folder. program and input both in same folder, Windows -10, Anaconda with python 3.x (upgraded version) The program link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9dzseqexv2bgts/convert_date_time_unix.py?dl=0

Comment: You don't need StringIO in your program  just pd.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])

Answer (score 2):

If csv has no header is necessary parameter `names` and `parse_dates` with `[1]` - try to parse second column to `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""156,2014-02-01 00:00:00.739166+01,41.8836718276551,12.4877775603346
187,1014-02-01 00:00:01.148457+01,41.9285433333333,12.4690366666667
297,2014-02-01 00:00:01.220066+01,41.8910686119733,12.4927045625339
89,2014-02-01 00:00:01.470854+01,41.7931766914244,12.4321219603157
79,2014-02-01 00:00:01.631136+01,41.90027472,12.46274618
191,2014-02-01 00:00:02.048546+01,41.8523047579646,12.5774065771898
343,2014-02-01 00:00:02.647839+01,41.8921718255185,12.4696996165151
341,2014-02-01 00:00:02.709888+01,41.9102125627332,12.4770004336041
260,2014-02-01 00:00:03.458195+01,41.8658208551143,12.4655221109313"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                parse_dates=[1], 
                names=['userid','datetime','latitude','longitude'])
#print (df)

#check dtypes if datetime it is OK
print (df['datetime'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
print (df)
   userid    datetime   latitude  longitude
0     156  1391209200  41.883672  12.487778
1     187  1391209201  41.928543  12.469037
2     297  1391209201  41.891069  12.492705
3      89  1391209201  41.793177  12.432122
4      79  1391209201  41.900275  12.462746
5     191  1391209202  41.852305  12.577407
6     343  1391209202  41.892172  12.469700
7     341  1391209202  41.910213  12.477000
8     260  1391209203  41.865821  12.465522
```

Another possible problem is bad data, in my sample second row:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""156,2014-02-01 00:00:00.739166+01,41.8836718276551,12.4877775603346
187,1014-02-01 00:00:01.148457+01,41.9285433333333,12.4690366666667
297,2014-02-01 00:00:01.220066+01,41.8910686119733,12.4927045625339
89,2014-02-01 00:00:01.470854+01,41.7931766914244,12.4321219603157
79,2014-02-01 00:00:01.631136+01,41.90027472,12.46274618
191,2014-02-01 00:00:02.048546+01,41.8523047579646,12.5774065771898
343,2014-02-01 00:00:02.647839+01,41.8921718255185,12.4696996165151
341,2014-02-01 00:00:02.709888+01,41.9102125627332,12.4770004336041
260,2014-02-01 00:00:03.458195+01,41.8658208551143,12.4655221109313"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 parse_dates=[1], 
                 names=['userid','datetime','latitude','longitude'])

#print (df)

#check dtypes - parse failed, get object dtype
print (df['datetime'].dtypes)
object
```

Parse to datetime with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `errors='coerce'` - it replace bad data to `NaT` and then replace NaT to some value e.g. `0` (`1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000`) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
print (df)
   userid                   datetime   latitude  longitude
0     156 2014-01-31 23:00:00.739166  41.883672  12.487778
1     187 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000  41.928543  12.469037
2     297 2014-01-31 23:00:01.220066  41.891069  12.492705
3      89 2014-01-31 23:00:01.470854  41.793177  12.432122
4      79 2014-01-31 23:00:01.631136  41.900275  12.462746
5     191 2014-01-31 23:00:02.048546  41.852305  12.577407
6     343 2014-01-31 23:00:02.647839  41.892172  12.469700
7     341 2014-01-31 23:00:02.709888  41.910213  12.477000
8     260 2014-01-31 23:00:03.458195  41.865821  12.465522


df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
print (df)
   userid    datetime   latitude  longitude
0     156  1391209200  41.883672  12.487778
1     187           0  41.928543  12.469037
2     297  1391209201  41.891069  12.492705
3      89  1391209201  41.793177  12.432122
4      79  1391209201  41.900275  12.462746
5     191  1391209202  41.852305  12.577407
6     343  1391209202  41.892172  12.469700
7     341  1391209202  41.910213  12.477000
8     260  1391209203  41.865821  12.465522
```

EDIT:

If there is also header and need replace column names need `header=0` add to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Thank you so much .. This is great ! But I can accept only one answer. Do you think you help me with this problem : Migration from 2.x to 3.x feels so many changes to be made .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970972/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str-in-python-3-x-anac/43971336#43971336

Comment: Yes, it is your decision which answer will be accepted.

Comment: In your second problem - which row in code return error?

Comment: It is about the same Unix Time Epoch based data manipulation.